# Designing a table like structure for an array of array of strings

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs

**HTML PAGE**:

```
<div>
    <ul ng-repeat='label in artifactClassification' >
        <li >
            <div ng-repeat='ClassificationTree in goTillRoot(label)'>{{ClassificationTree}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Above is the HTML template that I have. To give you a quick idea artifactClassification is an JSON. label is an object. I am passing this label in an function in JS that return ClassificationTree which is  an array of strings (of any size). What I am trying to do is create a table like structure that will display this array of array of string. The restriction is there could only be two columns. This should look something like:

```
xyz        xyz1
abc        abc1 
pqr        pqr1

mno        dsh
asd        234
as3        ff4

as3
ass
```

The above represents an array( here we have 5 arrays of string). The number could be anything. I need  help design this structure. Not sure what to use or where to begin from
The **output** that i am getting right now :

```
xyz
abc
asd
asd
a1d
sad
sad
```

Comment: What's the output of your code ?

Comment: Could you please make a JSFiddle or something containing a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're trying to do?